# Maven 2 multi module pom

Tags: java, testing, maven-2, functional-testing, cargo

I have recently started migrating my project from ant to maven. I have two module in my application which I am able to build using maven.

Now I have automated tests project which use Web Driver for testing UI functionality. What I am trying to do using maven is to build both module wars and deploy them on to tomcat. Then run automation tests against them and pass the build if automation test passes. I have configured my pom like this(just mentioning important part):

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
        <module>../module1</module>
        <module>../module2</module>
</modules>
```

Now Both the projects get build and deploy but It doesn't run automation tests. The reason I thought is that packaging type is POM. But If I change it to war it starts throwing error.

I can think of creating third pom for automation and parent pom to include that as module also. But I am thinking whether this is a right way. It should be a very common scenario and maven should be supporting it directly.

Comment: your test module is different project or just part of packaging structure ?

Comment: Then I would sugest to create a pom for that project and set it in hiererchy properly then run `mvn compile test`

Comment: How do you set hierarchy properly. The only thing I want to make sure is that whenever I run this build, it should build both dependent projects and then run thesee tests.

Comment: What is the automation module in question? Where are tests located? How do you deploy to the tomcat server? Lots of important details are missing to get an answer IMO.

Comment: Hi Pascal, automation module is the WebDriver based automation tests for testing UI. It depends on web war but there is no package dependency. I am deploying to tomcat using cargo maven plugin. I want to build web wars from source, on the fly just before running the automation tests, then deploy on tomcat and then run tests. I can do all these using ant build but unable to using maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (...) automation module is the WebDriver based automation tests for testing UI. It depends on web war but there is no package dependency. I am deploying to tomcat using cargo maven plugin. I want to build web wars from source, on the fly just before running the automation tests, then deploy on tomcat and then run tests. I can do all these using ant build but unable to using maven

This is definitely doable (and I've done it numerous time). But I'm not sure to understand  your current project structure (especially, where the tests are located).

Here is the structure I suggest:

```
.
├── functests
│   ├── pom.xml            // here we configure maven to run cargo & it tests
│   └── src
│       └── it
│           ├── java
│           │   └── ...    // functional tests will go here
│           └── resources
├── pom.xml                // aggregating pom
└── mywebapp               // the application under test
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   ├── java
        │   ├── resources
        │   └── webapp
        └── test
            ├── java
            └── resources
```

And for the details of the pom setup, have a look at [Functional testing with Maven, Cargo and Selenium](http://www.jroller.com/carlossg/entry/functional_testing_with_maven_cargo), it contains all the details required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that 2 war modules with a shared integration test module is a very common scenario.

However, you could get this working with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

- Set up a job in Hudson to deploy your parent level pom, which will result in the war modules being deployed as you currently have.
- On success of the previous job, trigger another job to run the integration-tests.

You may want to use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to activate integration testing, or more specifically to prevent integration tests from being executed during the first job.

I have earlier this year set-up a basic Hudson server in roughly an hour.
Hudson has direct support for maven builds and also provides a location for your projects maven site, including all of the quality reports etc.
You can also configure Hudson to "watch" your SCM, and initiate a build when it identifies a commit.

Comment: Thanks crowne.I was also thinking to follow the similar approach.I am using cruise control for continuous integration. I wanted to get an idea about whether building web wars and deploying them from build file of automation tests(which we are doing currently using ant) is a good idea or not and if it is then how to do it using maven.

Answer (score 0):

"I can think of creating third pom"
Do you have only two POMs? Each project/module needs its own POM.

Look here for more information on integration tests with maven: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing

**Edit:**
I don't understand exactly what your project layout looks like. But I guess it should look somehow like this:

File structure

```
myWebApp/
    pom.xml
    myWebApp-web/
        pom.xml
    myWebApp-integration-tests/
        pom.xml
```

/myWebApp/pom.xml

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <!-- packaging: war; here are the sources and unit tests -->
    <module>myWebApp-web</module>

    <!-- packaging: java; here are the integration tests -->
    <module>myWebApp-integration-tests</module>
</modules>
```

With this setup, `/myWebApp/mvn deploy` will execute the following steps:

1. Build the root project (does nothing, as there are no sources)
2. Build myWebApp-web
3. Deploy myWebApp-web (has to be configured in `/myWebApp/myWebApp-web/pom.xml`)
4. Execute tests in myWebApp-integration-tests

This should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply Arian. I have three pom's already. What I am trying to achieve is that this third project build should build the first two and then only trigger tests.

Comment: I extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arian... but it doesn't help. I have tried to make my question more meaningful. See if I am able to explain it clearly now. I don't think solution you provided will help in my case.